# apache 2.2 virtualhost multiple domain ssl - google

Tags: apache, ssl, dns, virtualhost

Good Day,

I have multiple domains assigned to virtualhosta but only for one domain I have a certificate.

google downloads certified links and assigns them to domains without a certificate.

For example:

The certified domain has a subpage: https://mydomain1.pl/page/1.html - This works fine....

But it also creates links without the certificate https://mydomain2.pl/page/1.html, https://mydomain3.pl/page/1.html, https://mydomain4.pl/page/1.html - such page does not exist.

My virtualhost:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
ServerName mydomain2.pl
ServerAlias mydomain2.pl

DocumentRoot /var/www/www/...

<Directory /var/www/www/.....>
        ...
</Directory>
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
ServerName mydomain3.pl
ServerAlias mydomain3.pl

DocumentRoot /var/www/www/...

<Directory /var/www/www/.....>
        ...
</Directory>
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
ServerName mydomain4.pl
ServerAlias mydomain4.pl

DocumentRoot /var/www/www/...

<Directory /var/www/www/.....>
        ...
</Directory>
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
        ServerName mydomain1.pl
        ServerAlias mydomain1.pl
        Redirect / https://mydomain1.pl/
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:443>
ServerName mydomain1.pl
ServerAlias mydomain1.pl
DocumentRoot /var/www/www/..

<Directory /var/www/www/...>
        SSLEngine on
 .......
</VirtualHost>
```

How can I fix it ? For demos that do not have a certificate and have already been indexed by google redirect to the appropriate domain and page, or how to disable https for domains without https

Comment: It's possible to create a single certificate that is valid for multiple domains using [Subject Alternative Names](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subject_Alternative_Name).

Comment: I do not want to add domains to certifikat. I have a domain mydomain3.pl which does not have a certificate but google gets me with the https value - additionally adds links that are in the domain mydomain1.pl which is certified.